# contacts added to an account are not saved across power off/on on Samsung Epic

Tags: android

When I add contacts with ACCOUNT_NAME, ACCOUNT_TYPE set to my custom values, the contacts are not saved after the Samsunc Epic is powered off.  I add contacts using the ArrayList ops and applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops) technique.

The same code works fine on the emulator and HTC EVO phones running 2.1 or 2.2. I am not currently using any sync provider logic.  Do I need to be a sync provider to use custom account fields?

If I use null values for ACCOUNT_NAME and ACCOUNT_TYPE the contacts are saved fine on both the Epic and HTC EVO, but I want an option to hide the contacts from typical "My Contacts" views.

Given that I'd like to be able to hide/unhide contacts dynamically, is using a custom account/type the best way to hide contacts or is there a better way?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot set the AccountType to custom values without implement AccountManager framework in full.

Nice tutorial http://www.finalconcept.com.au/article/view/android-account-manager-step-by-step-1 to get you started.

To hide the contacts (and provide power to do so in User's hand) this is the best way. But if your purpose is mere hiding that you can create a contact group which is set to display none and add your contacts to that group, you needn't take the pain to implement AccountManager.

Another side effect of implementing account manager is that contact belonging to custom account cannot be added/edited using native app (only names fields are visible).

Comment: Thanks for the link.  I'll ponder the tradeoffs of groups vs implementing an AccountManager. Any thoughts on why the HTC and LG phones retain contacts with a non-null AccountType and the Samsung Epic (possibly all Samsung devices) does not?  Same app code, same major Android version. Could there be something related to Account support that is open to interpretation and manufacturers have implemented it differently going on here?